# Chrome and font handling

Tags: google-chrome, image-processing, fonts, cross-browser

I have some larger font for my webpage. It is arial font. I Used Adobe BrowserLab and my site looks great in every browser but Chrome. Chrome makes the font all fuzzy and pixelated. Is chrome just a bad browser or is this on my end?

Comment: What version of Chrome is this?

Comment: I suggest downloading a newer version and testing it (e.g. maybe version 14 dev?)

Comment: my point is that the browser has been around for a while now and I have the most "stable" version. I have tested chrome on a local machine and on the "cloud" with adobe browserlab and everytime chrome's rendering of the fonts were grainy as all. Can I fix that on my end or is that how chrome is?

Comment: here is a screenshot I did with adobe browserlab the first is safari brower and the second is chrome 11 http://oi51.tinypic.com/faxy8k.jpg http://i56.tinypic.com/1hujk2_th.png

Comment: Do you happen to have GPU acceleration turned on? That might be why.

Comment: The adobe browserlab is its own "thing", I don't know if it has gpu on. Would you say most chrome users expirience thsi?

Comment: No I mean, do you have GPU acceleration turned on in *Chrome*? (Go to About:Flags and see.)

Comment: same thing in my chrome. some fonts render as, how would you say it, poo.

Comment: Can u show us some HTML?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any "font smoothing" in Google Chrome?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487427/is-there-any-font-smoothing-in-google-chrome)